# How to block alert box through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to block alert box if it is present in code. Im using an api that tells me the search result of my website and if any user enter

```
<script>alert('Just teasing')</script>
```

then it shows an alert box on my page how can i stop this alert?

Comment: Have you tried sanitizing your input instead of blocking alerts?

Comment: What does it have to do with jQuery? javascript = jQuery now? It's so new! :O

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you should sanitize you input as @Nikita commented.
If you want to accept JavaScript and only disable `alert` you can replace the `window.alert` function.

```
window.alert = function() { /* do nothing here */ }
```

Now calling `alert` won't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

When presenting the search results back to the user you need to ensure you HTML encode the output so the user would see the script rather than it being executed.